# Sukili how to close all windowses of app?

Tags: java, testing, sikuli

How to close all windowses of app after test with using Sikuli? I am using sikulix version 1.1.2, and to close window I can type ALT + F4, and it will close 1 window, but I need to close all exiting windowses of current app, how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
System.exit(0);
```

System.exit(0);

The "0" lets whomever called your program know that everything went OK. If, however, you are quitting due to an error, you should System.exit(1);, or with another non-zero number corresponding to the specific error.

Comment: It's not woking. The app does not closing.

Comment: I don't have any errors after executing your command, but I my test is faling, and I have an error log, which related to my test logs.

Comment: Take a screenshot of the application "X-Button" then do a new Screen and click it.


`Screen s = new Screen();`
`s.click(c:/user/ImageOfScreenshot.png);`

If you have any more question write me a mail: 
Nivisan1234@gmail.com